# sbt doesn't find class of managed dependency

Tags: scala, sbt, jepp

I try to include the build of jep (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jep/jep/2.24) into this scala project using sbt: https://github.com/shadaj/scalapy

So, instead of building jep manually via an unmanaged dependency, I want to include it as a managed dependency. Therefore I just included:

```
resolvers += "jep" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"

libraryDependencies += "jep" % "jep" % "2.24"
```

in the build.sbt

The .jar is getting downloaded and included in my .ivy2 folder but when compiling, sbt seems not to find it:

```
  > compile
[info] Updating {file:/C:/scalapy_indp/scalapy/}scalapy...
[info] Resolving org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;9 ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.1/scala-library-2.12.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.12.1!scala-library.jar (1406ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12.1/scala-reflect-2.12.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12.1!scala-reflect.jar (1156ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jep/jep/2.24/jep-2.24.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] jep#jep;2.24!jep.jar (188ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12.1/scala-compiler-2.12.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12.1!scala-compiler.jar (2469ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.12/1.0.6/scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.12;1.0.6!scala-xml_2.12.jar(bundle) (360ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.14.1/jline-2.14.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] jline#jline;2.14.1!jline.jar (250ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 16 Scala sources to C:\scalapy_indp\scalapy\target\scala-2.12\classes...
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.12.1. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 15.285 s
[error] C:\scalapy_indp\scalapy\src\gen\scala\me\shadaj\scalapy\py\ObjectTupleReaders.scala:2: not found: object jep
[error] import jep.Jep
[error]        ^
```

The errors of course keep coming for every Jep appearance in the code.

I'm absolutely not familiar with scala or sbt, I'm just trying to get this running without having to use unmanaged dependencies i.e. having it platform independent. Building jep manually seems to be platform dependent regarding the files which are being create:

> If the build succeeds it will create a directory jep/build which will
>   contain a jep.jar and the compiled C library of Jep, typically named
>   jep.so or jep.dll depending on your platform.

see https://github.com/mrj0/jep/wiki/Getting-Started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency is correctly setup, but the import is wrong.

Try

```
import org.nfunk.jep.JEP
```

instead.

--

Actually, I just realized those may be two different projects. The dependencies you included is this one: http://sens.cse.msu.edu/Software/jep-2.23/doc/website/doc/doc_usage.htm

Comment: Wow, you are absolutely right, I think. I didn't check the names. I was just thinking that the project in the maven repository was an old version but the functionality would be sufficient. Anyway, thanks a lot for the clarification